# Tomcat: cannot access to webapp at localhost

Tags: tomcat

I cannot access to my webapp  in my local PC.

```
http://localhost:8080/rasdaman/ows 
the requested resource is not available.
```

But http://localhost:8080 is available.

And from another PC in the LAN , webapp is accessable.

```
http://192.168.30.109:8080/rasdaman/ows
```

How do I make it available at localhost.

Comment: surprised, I guess, you must have rebooted many times till now to get it fixed, if not try rebooting and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Some steps to get to the root of this problem:

- Make sure that the given 192.x-IP address is indeed your computer. Do this by shutting down your tomcat, then access the webapp again from the other computer.
- Access the 192.x-IP from your own computer. (If it works: Shut down your tomcat, retry)
- Check tomcat's configuration for different virtual hosts (did you add
  additional hosts in tomcat's server.xml?)
- Check your local computer's firewall settings.

One of them should lead you to the cause

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your Tomcat server is only listening on IP address 192.168.30.109, and not on 127.0.0.1.